# HTTP Authentication in Restlet, authenticating child URL

Tags: restlet

I am using HTTP Digest authentication mechanism in the server side and client is firefox.

This is the server side code

```
Application application = new Vehicle();

component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(application);
component.getDefaultHost().attach("/home",new Home());

DigestAuthenticator guard = new DigestAuthenticator(null, "TestRealm","mySecretServerKey");
Instantiates a Verifier of identifier/secret couples based on a  simple Map.
MapVerifier mapVerifier = new MapVerifier();
```

Load a single static login/secret pair.

```
mapVerifier.getLocalSecrets().put("login", "secret".toCharArray());
guard.setWrappedVerifier(mapVerifier);
```

Guard the restlet

```
guard.setNext(application);
component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(guard);  
component.start();
```

In home class

```
Router router = new Router(getContext());
router.attach("/People", People.class);
router.attach("/categories/",Categories.class);

return router;
```

if i request `http://localhost:8182/`  Http authentication is working but `http://localhost:8182/home/categories/` is not asking for any `http authentication` if first we try for  `/home/categories/` instead of `http://localhost:8182/` it will give out the result with out any authentication mechanism. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching the guard only to the default route, so the routes that are not matching any other routes. See the javadoc for attachDefault :

```
 * Attaches a Resource class to this router as the default target to invoke
 * when no route matches. It actually sets a default route that scores all
 * calls to 1.0.
```

Your other routes are not the default routes and so they are not guarded

```
router.attach("/People", People.class);
router.attach("/categories/",Categories.class);
```

You must wire the guard between each route that you want to protect like this :

```
DigestAuthenticator peopleGuard = new DigestAuthenticator(null, "TestRealm","mySecretServerKey");
peopleGuard.setNext(People.class);
router.attach("/People", peopleGuard);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will try out your suggestion.